# Backlink from subdomain

Tags: seo, domains, subdomain, backlinks, traffic

I wanted to know how the traffic is calculated if I get a backlink from a subdomain page. For example, a website corriere.it has over 20M organic traffic, but roma.corriere.it has 500K

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Who is calculating what to what end? I don't think SEO works this way.  The quality, relevancy, age of the pages being linked from are what are important, and there is "secret sauce" in determining their value. While domain is a factor, the specific page is usually a more significant factor.

Comment: The "link juice" is passed from the main domain or subdomain? For example even if they have different DR

Comment: there is a lot of logic in SEO. Often if you think about it you can intuit the answer.   "Link Juice" must derive from the subdomain - the parent domain is not involved in this equation.  (It is, of course the subject of an earlier equation - his did the subdomain get its.juice)